# Sort a mixed list of headings in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a long list of headings in `org-mode`:

```
* Tasks [/]
** TODO Foo
** TODO Bar
** DONE World
** DONE Abba
```

that I want to sort as follows:

```
* Tasks [/]
** TODO Bar
** TODO Foo
** DONE Abba
** DONE World
```

With `org-sort-entries` I can either obtain

```
* Tasks [/]
** DONE Abba
** TODO Bar
** TODO Foo
** DONE World
```

(i.e. alphabetical order), or

```
* Tasks [/]
** TODO Foo
** TODO Bar
** DONE World
** DONE Abba
```

(i.e. grouping according to the status).

In other words, I want to sort the `TODO` and the `DONE` items alphabetically, but keep them in two blocks. How could I achieve it? I want to keep the whole set of headings in the same subtree!

### Edit:

I didn't manage to utilize the suggestions below. So, I tried to use the tips provided below to come up with the solution I need. Here is the code I have:

```lisp
(defun drorata-sort-TODO-DONE-headings ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; Sort according to the TODO/DONE keywords
    (org-sort-entries t ?o)
    ;; Now there is a block of TODO's and a block of DONE's
    ;; Mark the TODO's
    (next-line)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (search-forward-regexp "[*].* DONE" nil t)
    (beginning-of-line)
    ;; Sort the marked region (of TODO's) alphabetically
    (org-sort-entries t ?a)
    ;; Now its time to sort the DONE's
    (search-forward "[*].* DONE" nil t)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    ;; How can I find all headings labeled with DONE in the current level?
    )
)
```

My idea is to mark the headings that are labeled by `TODO` and sort them alphabetically and then do the same to the `DONE` headings. So far, I have it working only for the `TODO`'s...

Comment: If you create main headings (e.g., `* TASKS`; `* COMPLETED`) and move all your stuff over to subheadings (e.g., `** TODO`; `**DONE`), then you can sort and reorganize the whole buffer (hundreds of tasks) in one fell swoop.  I've posted a couple of screenshots to demonstrate how the proposed layout would look.  The solution does not rely upon selecting regions, but instead acts upon a main heading and organizes everything under that main heading -- i.e., all subheadings are organized.  The code in my answer will regroup tasks by refiling them underneath the correct main heading.

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to have all headings under one parent. The parent has a progress indicator that I want to use - if I'll split the dones and todos in different parents the progress indicator will break. Nevertheless, I want the headings to be firstly grouped by their status, and secondly according to an alphabetical order.

Comment: What does your parent look like?  My understanding of a parent is that it has only one star (e.g., `* PARENT`), and children have more than one star.  The key to this working is that the `** TODO` and `** DONE` both be children, *not* parents.  You **can** keep the `** TODO` and `** DONE` as children underneath *the same parent*, and organize everything underneath the parent *without* selecting a region.  Just place the cursor on the parent and type `M-x org-sort-entries`

Comment: @lawlist: See my edit to the OP. With `org-sort-entries` I can either sort according to the key (`TODO` or `DONE`) or alphabetically. In the for former case I get two "blocks" (one for `TODO`s and one for `DONE`s) without any reasonable order inside the blocks. On the latter case I get a mixed (alphabetically ordered) list of headings.

Comment: **STEP #1**:  Place the cursor on the parent.   **STEP #2**:  `M-x org-sort-entries RET a RET`  **STEP #3**:  `M-x org-sort-entries RET o RET`.  **STEP # 4**:  Crack open your favorite beverage and have a drink.

Comment: @lawlist: What would you have? Vodka Martini? Shaken or stirred? Thanks! I feel dumb. Would you like to turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Don't feel bad -- it took me multiple attempts a few months ago to figure out that I need to sort first by `a`, then by `o`, then by `p`, and then by `t`.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: In the better-late-than-never category: you should accept @lawlist 's answer!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**THE SHORT ANSWER**

- **STEP # 1**:  Place the cursor on the parent.
- **STEP # 2**:  `M-x org-sort-entries RET a RET`
- **STEP # 3**:  `M-x org-sort-entries RET o RET`
- **STEP # 4**:  Crack open your favorite beverage and have a drink.

---

**THE LONG-WINDED ANSWER**

To expand upon the answer of @pmr (i.e., sorting a selected region), one may also wish to consider acting upon main headings to organize subheadings.  For example, I like to perform a multi-sort -- first by alphabetic, second by todo-order, third by priority, and fourth by time.  For subheadings that do not contain deadlines and contain only one type of todo status, it is sufficient for my needs to only sort by alphabetic.  Set forth below is a sample function that I use to sort the entire buffer containing various main headings and subheadings.  Here is the cheat-sheet from `org-sort-entries`:

```
Sort: [a]lpha  [n]umeric  [p]riority  p[r]operty  todo[o]rder  [f]unc
               [t]ime [s]cheduled  [d]eadline  [c]reated
               A/N/P/R/O/F/T/S/D/C means reversed.
```

---

**NOTE**:  `org-sort-entries` uses the `current-time` when sorting entries based on time-stamp if the entry does not contain a time-stamp.  The consequence of using the `current-time` is that undated entries will be sorted prior to future tasks containing time-stamps when sorting with the options `t`, `c`, `s`, or `d`.  To weight the undated entries so that they are sorted *after* the dated entries, it is possible to use a later date than the `current-time`.  The relevant *let-bound* variable is defined as `(now (current-time))`, and its usage within the function is written as `(org-float-time now)`.  This can be dealt with many different ways -- e.g., modifying the code containing `(org-float-time now)` with something containing an artificial date far off into the future -- e.g., `(org-time-string-to-seconds "<2030-12-31 Tue>")`.

```lisp
(defun lawlist-sort ()
  (when
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (re-search-backward "^\\* CONTACTS" nil t)
        (re-search-forward  "^\\*\\* \\(Planning\\)" nil t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (re-search-backward "^\\* CONTACTS" nil t)
    (org-sort-entries t ?a) )
  (when
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (re-search-backward "^\\* DONE" nil t)
        (re-search-forward  "^\\*\\* \\(None\\)" nil t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (re-search-backward "^\\* DONE" nil t)
    (org-sort-entries t ?a) )
  (when
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (re-search-backward "^\\* UNDATED" nil t)
        (re-search-forward  "^\\*\\* \\(Someday\\)" nil t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (re-search-backward "^\\* UNDATED" nil t)
    (org-sort-entries t ?a) )
  (when
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (re-search-backward "^\\* EVENTS" nil t)
        (re-search-forward  "^\\*\\* \\(Reference\\|Delegated\\|Postponed\\|Waiting\\)" nil t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (re-search-backward "^\\* EVENTS" nil t)
    (org-sort-entries t ?a)
    (org-sort-entries t ?o)
    (org-sort-entries t ?p)
    (org-sort-entries t ?t) )
  (when
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (re-search-backward "^\\* TASKS" nil t)
        (re-search-forward "^\\*\\* \\(Active\\|Next Action\\|Hold\\|Canceled\\)" nil t))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (re-search-backward "^\\* TASKS" nil t)
    (org-sort-entries t ?a)
    (org-sort-entries t ?o)
    (org-sort-entries t ?p)
    (org-sort-entries t ?t) ) )
```

---

Here is an example of how to sort and reorganize an entire buffer containing main headings and subheadings.  This is especially useful if the user desires synchronization with the Toodledo server using the `org-toodledo` library:  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo  To speed up the process when reorganizing a buffer containing hundreds of subheadings, the user may wish to consider suppressing the messages by modifying the functions responsible -- however, that is beyond the scope of this answer.

```lisp
(setq org-todo-keywords '(
  (sequence
  "Active(a)"
  "Next Action(n)"
  "Canceled(c)"
  "Hold(h)"
  "Reference(r)"
  "Delegated(d)"
  "Waiting(w)"
  "Postponed(P)"
  "Someday(s)"
  "Planning(p)"
  "|"
  "None(N)") ))

(defun lawlist-reorganize ()
(interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "test.org")
    (setq buffer-read-only nil)
    (lawlist-refile-tasks)
    (lawlist-refile-events)
    (lawlist-refile-undated)
    (lawlist-refile-contacts)
    (lawlist-refile-done)
    (lawlist-sort)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (save-buffer)
    (setq buffer-read-only t)))

(defun lawlist-refile-tasks ()
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.org::* TASKS")
      (org-archive-save-context-info nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "^\\* TASKS" nil t)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "* TASKS\n\n"))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while
        (re-search-backward
          "^\\*\\* \\(Active\\|Next Action\\|Hold\\|Canceled\\)" nil t)
      (org-archive-subtree))))

(defun lawlist-refile-events ()
  (let* (
      (org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.org::* EVENTS")
      (org-archive-save-context-info nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "^\\* EVENTS" nil t)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "* EVENTS\n\n"))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while
        (re-search-backward
          "^\\*\\* \\(Reference\\|Delegated\\|Postponed\\|Waiting\\)" nil t)
      (org-archive-subtree))))

(defun lawlist-refile-undated ()
  (let* (
      (org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.org::* UNDATED")
      (org-archive-save-context-info nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "^\\* UNDATED" nil t)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "* UNDATED\n\n"))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while
        (re-search-backward
          "^\\*\\* \\(Someday\\)" nil t)
      (org-archive-subtree))))

(defun lawlist-refile-done ()
  (let* (
      (org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.org::* DONE")
      (org-archive-save-context-info nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "^\\* DONE" nil t)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "* DONE\n\n"))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while
        (re-search-backward
          "^\\*\\* \\(None\\)" nil t)
      (org-archive-subtree))))

(defun lawlist-refile-contacts ()
  (let* (
      (org-archive-location "/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.org::* CONTACTS")
      (org-archive-save-context-info nil))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (unless (re-search-forward "^\\* CONTACTS" nil t)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (insert "* CONTACTS\n\n"))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (while
        (re-search-backward
          "^\\*\\* \\(Planning\\)" nil t)
      (org-archive-subtree))))
```

---

Here is a sample clean-up function to put proper spacing between entries and delete any empty lines at the end of the buffer -- the regexp assumes headings and subheadings are all flush-left:

```lisp
(defun lawlist-cleanup ()
(interactive)
  (let ((query-replace-lazy-highlight nil))
    (replace-regexp "\n+\\*\\* " "\n\n** " nil (point-min) (point-max))
    (replace-regexp "\n+\\* " "\n\n\n* " nil (point-min) (point-max))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (delete-blank-lines)
    (let ((trailnewlines (abs (skip-chars-backward "\n\t"))))
      (if (> trailnewlines 0)
        (delete-char trailnewlines))) ))
```

---

This solution does not rely upon selecting regions, but instead acts upon each main heading and organizes everything under that main heading -- i.e., all subheadings are organized. The code in this answer will regroup entries by refiling them underneath the correct main heading.  For example -- if a task has been completed, the completed subheading will be `** None` -- the code will look for all subheadings with `** None` and move them to the main heading of `* DONE`, and then sort them alphabetically.

The main headings are:  `* TASKS`; `* EVENTS`; `* SOMEDAY`; `* CONTACTS`; `* DONE`.

The following subheadings were chosen because they are a method of Getting Things Done, and the Toodledo server uses this same methodology:  `** Active`; `** Next Action`; `** Hold`; `** Canceled`; `** Reference`; `** Delegated`; `** Postponed`; `** Waiting`; `** Someday`; `** Planning`; `** None`.

```
* TASKS

  ** Active

  ** Next Action

  ** Hold

  ** Canceled

* EVENTS

  ** Reference

  ** Delegated

  ** Postponed

  ** Waiting

* SOMEDAY

  ** Someday

* CONTACTS

  ** Planning

* DONE

  ** None
```

Answer (score 1):

The top-level interactive function `org-sort` will (in your case) call `org-sort-entries`, which acts on a region. You just need to make sure your region does not include the other block.

To programmatically extend the region over a block of TODO keywords you can combine `outline-get-next-sibling` with `org-heading-components` and an active region.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [lawlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231431/sort-a-mixed-list-of-headings-in-org-mode/22232709#22232709)'s short answer, here's an interactive function to group by `TODO` keyword and sort alphabetically. This achieves the sort by:

1. First sorting alphabetically
2. Then sorting by `TODO` keyword

Note this works because the `TODO`-sort in `org-sort-entries` preserves the initial alphabetical sort.

```
(defun apl-org-sort-entries-todo-alphabetical ()
  "Group Org-mode entries by TODO keyword and sort alphabetically.

This function achieves this by first sorting alphabetically and
then sorting by TODO keyword. This works because the TODO-sort in
`org-sort-entries' preserves the initial alphabetical sort."
  (interactive)
  ;; First sort alphabetically
  (org-sort-entries t ?a)
  ;; Then sort by TODO keyword
  (org-sort-entries t ?o)
  ;; Rotate subtree to show children
  (org-cycle)               ; SUBTREE -> FOLDED
  (org-cycle)               ; FOLDED -> CHILDREN
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to solve with ordinary replace and sort function. I think it's not useful. But it's one of possible answer.

(Character "@" must be unique string.)

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `fundamental-mode`
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> `@`
3. <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>
4. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `@[*][ ]` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd> `*`<kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>
5. <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>
6. <kbd>M-></kbd>
7. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sort-lines`
8. <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>
9. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd> `@` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd>

Input:

```
* TODO Foo
** TODO1
todo1

* TODO Bar
** TODO2
todo2

* DONE World
** DONE1
done1

* DONE Abba
** DONE2
done2
```

Output:

```
* DONE Abba
** DONE2
done2

* DONE World
** DONE1
done1

* TODO Bar
** TODO2
todo2

* TODO Foo
** TODO1
todo1
```