# Emacs Evil mode function to Quickly Sort snippets

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, evil-mode

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is rapid manual sorting of lots of notes and snippets of text.

What I would like to it mark a set of registers, (basically headlines in org-mode) for example

1-Tasks 2-Inbox, 3-Reference, 4-Someday

Then I want to highlight bits of a messy notes file, invoke a function, and have it kill the selection, yank it to one of the marks, and then return to the place i was before to process more snippets. So far I know I need to use:

```
    (evil-paste-after COUNT &optional REGISTER YANK-HANDLER)
```

but not sure exactly how to structure the function.

Comment: As event_jr has mentioned, *manual* sorting can be accomplished with `org-refile` and that can even be done with multiple files -- i.e., from one file to another file.  You might also be interested in `org-sort-entries` which can be done manually, or can be done in a function with multiple sorting actions that have been hard-coded:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489  If you just want to display the results, but not reorganize your org files, then you may be interested in a tag search or a word search (not tag dependent): http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: Could you post what the buffer should look like before and after? Sounds like you should include the desired point and register state too (in evil we yank to registers, not marks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [org-refile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Refiling-notes.html) with some custom targets?

Comment: That's pretty close, but I need it to work with arbitrary text, not just text that's in a headline. So far I've set "org-refile-active-region-within-subtree" to be able to work with arbitrary text, but then the refile function turns the whole text into headings