# Duplicate tree-structure in org-mode archive

Tags: emacs, archive, org-mode

In Orgmode under Emacs, is there already a way programmed to automatically duplicate in the archive the tree structure *above* an item being archived?

My new org-mode structure in a file looks like the following:

```
* CONFIGURE
** Operating Systems
*** Debian Unstable
*** Demodyne

** Machines
(...)
** Software
(...)
```

After archiving the entry "Demodyne", I would like the archive to contain the following:

```
* CONFIGURE
** Operating Systems
*** Demodyne
```

I thought I had seen it in the documentation of org-mode when I started using it many many years ago, but did not find anything like this in the documentation of the latest version at http://orgmode.org/manual/ (the entry on archiving http://orgmode.org/manual/Archiving.html#Archiving is rather succinct). I feel I could program it, but I would rather not if it has been done before...

Comment: You can run `org-sort-entries` programmatically and organize in that fashion following an archive.  I have a custom function that sorts by four levels -- `?a` then `?o` then `?p` then `?t` on my tasks/events.  On Someday and Done I just do alphabetize by title.  You can also pinpoint the target for archival programmatically (headline and file) by using `org-archive-location` on a let-bound basis:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489  I actually use this method of refiling to send any task/event anywhere I choose.

Comment: I will try to program it and to publish it in https://github.com/jyby/JyByLisp

Comment: I cannot believe this is not built-in.

Answer (score 0):

There's a partial solution for this at https://gist.github.com/edgimar/072d99d8650abe81a9fe7c8687c0c993.

This could be a really nice solution, however, it only works for me when executing on a single `DONE` task. If I try extending it to all `DONE` tasks in a subtree using `org-map-entries` as shown below, it creates a new top-level `* ARCHIVED` heading each time it's run. Is there a way to avoid this unwanted behavior?

**Example of undesired behavior with `org-map-entries`**

Define function to operate on all `DONE` tasks in current subtree:

```
(defun org-archive-done-tasks ()
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries 'org-archive-subtree-hierarchical "/DONE" 'tree))
```

*Note*: `org-archive-subtree-hierarchical` is found in above link.

Now if I take the following buffer

```
* Project 1
** TODO Task 1
** TODO Task 2
** TODO Task 3
```

and mark Task 1 `DONE`, run `org-archive-done-tasks` on Project 1, and then do the same for Task 2, the buffer results in

```
* ARCHIVED
** Project 1
*** DONE Task 1

* ARCHIVED
** Project 1
*** DONE Task 2

* Project 1
** TODO Task 3
```

Here is the desired result, which is what would happen if `org-archive-subtree-hierarchical` were run directly on `** DONE Task 1` and then `** DONE Task 2` (as children of `* Project 1`)

```
* ARCHIVED
** Project 1
*** DONE Task 1
*** DONE Task 2

* Project 1
** TODO Task 3
```

Is the desired behavior possible using `org-map-entries`? Is there a better method of executing `org-archive-subtree-hierarchical` on all `DONE` tasks in a subtree multiple times without duplicating the archive target heading?