# Emacs org-mode - how can I refile a subtree to a new file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I maintain an org file with a lot of draft posts ([here's a link to the file](https://github.com/yanivdll/prodissues/blob/master/content/pages/posts_drafts.org)). My workflow is to work on a draft post, and once it's ready to get published, I copy it to a new org file, which I then push to my pelican based [blog](http://prodissues.com).

What I would have liked to do, is use the refile command to help me with moving the subtree, which represent a post, to the new post file.

My research led me to few answers here at stack-overflow. I implemented this function:

```
(require 'org-element)

(defun me/org-file-from-subtree (&optional name)
"Cut the subtree currently being edited and create a new file
from it.

If called with the universal argument, prompt for new filename,
otherwise use the subtree title."
(interactive "P")
(org-back-to-heading)
(let ((filename (cond
               (current-prefix-arg
                (expand-file-name
                 (read-file-name "New file name: ")))
               (t
                (concat
                 (expand-file-name
                  (org-element-property :title
                                        (org-element-at-point))
                  default-directory)
                 ".org")))))
(org-cut-subtree)
(find-file-noselect filename)
(with-temp-file filename
  (org-mode)
  (yank))))
```

Source: Jonathan Leech-Pepin's answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/568300/525565).

This function works, but it doesn't carry the footnotes defined in the subtree I'm trying to refile. Any idea how I can cut the footnotes together with the subtree?

**UPDATE:**
Adding an example for what I'm trying to achieve. Given this org file:

```
* Drafts
** First Post
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, fermentum vulputate laoreet eligendi,[fn:1]
magna wisi elit scelerisque

** Second Post
Ultrices natoque sollicitudin duis curabitur, 
quam pellentesque ante aliquam nulla aenean, 
dui egestas ipsum adipiscing, sem nulla sit nisl, 
parturient[fn:2] habitasse ac amet at eget suspendisse.

* Footnotes

[fn:1] This is a footnote for the first post 

[fn:2] This is a footnote for the second post
```

Now, what I want to be able to do is move the first post, together with it's footnote (fn:1) to a new file.

Thanks. Yaniv

(I should say that I'm new to emacs, and still don't really comprehend the *lisp* code I put in my init... so I might be missing something very basic)

Comment: See the following detailed example of how to programmatically use `org-archive-subtree` / `org-archive-location` / `org-archive-save-context-info` to move subtrees anywhere you want:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489  I do not use footnotes, so you would need to see if `org-archive-subtree` handles them in a way that meets your needs.  If it is just an issue of expanding the region being selected, then consider modifying your post to provide a detailed example of what it is that you are trying to cut/move so people can use your test data to create a working solution.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist, the example you provided is very insightful. Unfortunately, the `org-archive-subtree` doesn't pick the footnotes with the subtree.

Comment: I recommend advising `org-archive-subtree` to run a function at the tail end that pastes the footnote information in the target file at the desired location  `(let (footnote) (save-excursion (org-back-to-heading t) (org-narrow-to-subtree) (while (re-search-forward "\\[fn:[0-9]+\\]" nil t) (push (cons (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)) nil) footnote)) (widen) (org-end-of-subtree t t) (setq footnote (mapcar (lambda (x) (and (search-forward (car x) nil t nil) (cons (car x) (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 0) (point-at-eol))))) footnote))) footnote)`

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. I'm not sure I know how to mend the `org-archive-subtree`. Any chance you can advise how your snippet can be added to the function I use to refile to a new file (see in my original question - `me/org-file-from-subtree`)?