# selecting entries in org-mode with a deadline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For a number of reasons I have a single file org-mode file with a long todo list, where priority tasks have deadlines and non-priority ones have no deadlines.
The file is now too big and slowing down my shortcuts. My goal is to split the tasks with and without a deadline into two separate files.
 I have tried to display the tasks on a calendar and copy the most recent ones (org-mode displays up to 14 days), but that will only allow me to copy their headings and not the task body.

Is there a way to select only the entries (marked with a "*") with a deadline, leaving everything else out?

Comment: It sounds like you have not yet explored the power of `M-x org-agenda` -- my daily workflow uses a combination of sorting my entries by four criteria -- first by `a`, then by `o`, then by `p`, and finally by `t` with `org-sort-entries` for the flat-text `org-mode` file, and then when I want to pull up a custom search I use the three org-agenda functions as needed `org-agenda-list`, `org-tags-view`, and `org-search-view`.  If you want a complex example to sort programmatically in the flat-text `org-mode` file, here is a link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22232709/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could easily sort your file by deadline (C-c ^ and then d) and then find the last headline including a deadline, mark all deadline tasks with C-Space and cut and paste these headlines into a new file.

Does this help?

Comment: thanks, but the sorting part didn't work. Is this a custom shortcut you've set?

Comment: No, it is simply org-sort

Comment: You may have to position the cursor appropriately, before trying to sort - see the doc for the function `org-sort-entries`.

Comment: thanks, I just saw that I had to select all the entries before sorting. works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The sort/cut/paste approach in the previous answer should work fine. The following alternative approach may be of interest if you want to go deeper into org-mode, but it requires some knowledge of lisp as well as a few org-mode functions.

The idea is to refile entries using `org-refile`. But that refiles only a single entry, so we map it over all entries using `org-map-entries`.

The idea is simple but the implementation is a bit messier. First, we need to tell `org-refile` where to refile by setting the variable `org-refile-targets`, but since there might be a global setting, we need to use `let` to redefine this variable locally.

Second, we need to select the right entries: `org-map-entries` takes a `matching` argument that can be used for that; in particular, `"DEADLINE<>\"\""` (testing that the DEADLINE special property of the entry is not equal to the empty string) can be used for that. This then *almost* works:

```
(let ((org-refile-targets '(("refiled.org" :level . 1))))
  (org-map-entries #'org-refile "DEADLINE<>\"\"" 'file))
```

Almost, but not quite: every time `org-refile` is called, it leaves point at the beginning of the next line and org-map-entries moves it to the end of the line, before attempting the next match; so if you have two DEADLINE entries, one after the other, the second one will be missed. The fix for that is to make sure that you set `org-map-continue-from` to a position in the buffer that will not miss the next headline. Putting all of this together, you can define the following two functions:

```
(defun ndk-refile ()
  (org-refile)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (setq org-map-continue-from (point)))

(defun ndk-refile-all ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-refile-targets '(("refiled.org" :level . 1))))
    (org-map-entries #'ndk-refile "DEADLINE<>\"\"" 'file)))
```

Create the `refiled.org` file with a `* Tasks` first-level heading and then call the latter function with `M-x ndk-refile-all`. You will be asked about the refiling destination on *each* call of `org-refile` unfortunately, but I didn't dig into how to tame the fit of interaction that it suffers from. Suggestions towards that end are welcome.

BTW, make sure to back up the original file.